# From which version of Jenkins version are supported by Java 1.8?

Tags: java, jenkins

Actually am using Jenkins 2.107.3, I want to know whether this version supports Java 1.8 or not..??
In addition to that, from which version of Jenkins version are supported by Java 1.8..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [official release](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/04/10/jenkins-has-upgraded-to-java-8/) starting from Jenkins version 2.54, Jenkins is fully compatible with java 1.8 and its mandatory to use it. So version 2.107.3 is compatible with it.

Comment: Thanks Sagar for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins version 2.54 and higher not only supports, but *requires* Java 8 to run.

*See: [Starting with 2.54, Jenkins now requires Java 8](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/04/10/jenkins-has-upgraded-to-java-8/)*

See, yes, version 2.107.3 supports Java 1.8, and it has been supported since at least version 2.54.

Looking back through the [older changelog](https://jenkins.io/changelog-old/), the first mention of JDK8 is for version 1.557 (release date 2014/03/31).

Comment: Thanks Erwin for the quick response.